# Render: Deployment failed

Tags: node.js, express, npm, deployment

I m trying to deploy a node applicaton on Render as deployment service ....but end up getting **build failed** each time.
Here are the logs from the event of deployment:

```
   Jul 8 07:41:12 PM  ==> Cloning from https://github.com/nileshp07/Natours...
Jul 8 07:41:15 PM  ==> Checking out commit 6b28421ce689c5171b48e0f038cc352471c844e0 in branch main
Jul 8 07:41:19 PM  ==> Using Node version 20.4.0 via /opt/render/project/src/package.json
Jul 8 07:41:19 PM  ==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
Jul 8 07:41:21 PM  ==> Running build command 'npm install'...
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR!
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR! While resolving: eslint-config-airbnb@18.2.1
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR! Found: eslint@8.43.0
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR!   dev eslint@"^8.43.0" from the root project
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || >=8.0.0" from @eslint-community/eslint-utils@4.4.0
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR!   node_modules/@eslint-community/eslint-utils
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR!     @eslint-community/eslint-utils@"^4.2.0" from eslint@8.43.0
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR!   5 more (eslint-config-prettier, eslint-plugin-import, ...)
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR!
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR! peer eslint@"^5.16.0 || ^6.8.0 || ^7.2.0" from eslint-config-airbnb@18.2.1
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR!   dev eslint-config-airbnb@"^18.2.1" from the root project
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR!
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@7.32.0
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^5.16.0 || ^6.8.0 || ^7.2.0" from eslint-config-airbnb@18.2.1
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR!     dev eslint-config-airbnb@"^18.2.1" from the root project
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR!
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR!
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR!
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR! For a full report see:
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR! /opt/render/.cache/_logs/2023-07-08T14_11_21_566Z-eresolve-report.txt
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /opt/render/.cache/_logs/2023-07-08T14_11_21_566Z-debug-0.log
Jul 8 07:41:22 PM  ==> Build failed
```

I guess it has something to do with my npm packages. Can anyone help me out with this?
Any help would be gratefull :)

Answer (score 1):

Install the correct versions of each package, which are listed by the command

```
$ npm view  eslint-config-airbnb@18.2.1 peerDependencies
{
  eslint: '^5.16.0 || ^6.8.0 || ^7.2.0',
  'eslint-plugin-import': '^2.22.1',
  'eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y': '^6.4.1',
  'eslint-plugin-react': '^7.21.5',
  'eslint-plugin-react-hooks': '^4 || ^3 || ^2.3.0 || ^1.7.0'
}
```

You have installed `eslint@^8.43.0` in your project, but `eslint-config-airbnb@18.2.1` requires the `eslint` as its peer dependency and has compatible versions: `'^5.16.0 || ^6.8.0 || ^7.2.0'`. If you are using `npm` v7+, it will display this warning.

The choices:

1. If you are sure the `eslint-config-airbnb@18.2.1` is compatible with `eslint@^8.43.0`, you can ignore the warning and use `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`.
2. Upgrading the `eslint-config-airbnb` package to latest version (`19.0.4` currently)
3. Downgrading the `eslint` package to `^7.2.0` version.
4. Downgrading `npm` to a version less than 7. `npm v7.0.0` ships with Node.js 15.0.0, which means you can downgrade the Node to a version less than 15.

Further reading: [Peer Dependencies](https://nodejs.org/fa/blog/npm/peer-dependencies)

Comment: Yaa i got that figured .... i upgraded all the packages and it worked. But i m still not able to understand what does peer dependencies actually mean?